# R: Function in a loaded package cannot be found

Tags: r

I've installed and loaded the `merTools` library where the `shuffle` function is found. However, I've used this function (`shuffle(bwt)`, where `bwt` is a data frame) but it gives me the error `could not find function "shuffle"`. How is that?

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: Please go through the suggested solutions from the linked post. If they do not resolve your issue, then post reproducible example code, together with `sessionInfo()` output.